# How to find storage details for a particular folder using google drive api

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I want find storage details for a particular folder using google drive api
Basically i am integrating google drive api with my current app to reduce the cost. But i want to notify user about the amount of storage used

Comment: You say: " storage details for a particular folder" - what details are you looking for? Size, location etc? You say: " reduce the cost" What cost? computing time? fees?. You say: "notify user" What user? How do you want to notify them? This question is incomplete and any answers would rely on assumptions about your project.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder) a folder is a type of file that only contain metadata and is used for file organization.

It also states that: *a folder is a file with the MIME type application/vnd.google-apps.folder and with no extension.*

Therefore, to access folder's details such as its size we would use the same method as with files, in this case we would use the [GET method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) that would return a object with the folder details.

This would be an example of this in Python:

```
file = drive_service.files().get('FOLDER ID').execute()
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)